# Displaying data for multi-level relationships with sideloaded json and Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an app that has many layers of relationships. I have a Tournament with n rounds, each round has n matchups, each matchup has n seats, each seat has 1 entry. Here's a sample of the json structure:

```
{
  "tournament": {
    "id":                     1,
    "title":                  "March Madness!!!",
    "rounds":                 [1],
    "active_round":           1
  },
  "rounds": [
    {
      "id":         1,
      "tournament": 1,
      "matchups":   [1, 2]
    },
    {
      "id":         2,
      "tournament": 1,
      "matchups":   [3]
    }
  ],
  "matchups": [
    { "id": 1, "round": 1, "seats": [1, 2] },
    { "id": 2, "round": 1, "seats": [3, 4] },
    { "id": 3, "round": 2, "seats": [5, 6] }
  ],
  "seats": [
    { "id": 1, "matchup": 1, "entry": 1 },
    { "id": 2, "matchup": 1, "entry": 2 },
    { "id": 3, "matchup": 2, "entry": 3 },
    { "id": 4, "matchup": 2, "entry": 4 },
    { "id": 5, "matchup": 3, "entry": "" },
    { "id": 6, "matchup": 3, "entry": "" }
  ],
  "entries": [
    { 
      "id":               1,
      "seats":             [1]
    },
    { 
      "id":               2,
      "seats":             [2]
    },
    { 
      "id":               3,
      "seats":             [3]
    },
    { 
      "id":               4,
      "seats":             [4]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the content out. Here's my router.js:

```
App.Router.map( function() {
    this.resource('tournament', { path: "/" });
});

App.TournamentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        [..we just get the data return the json object above to setupController...]
        });
    },

    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
        [i do a little data computation here prior to the renderTemplate function]
    },

    renderTemplate: function () {
        var controller = this.controllerFor('tournament');
        this.render('tournament');
    }
});
```

My tournament.hbs template looks like this:

```
    <h1>{{tournament.title}}</h1>
    {{#each round in rounds}} Round id: {{round.id}} <br/>
        {{#each matchup in round.matchups}} matchup id: {{matchup.id}}
            <div class="matchup">
                {{#each seat in matchup.seats}}
                    <div class="entry">
                        {{seat.entry.id}}
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
```

And I'm getting the following on screen:

```
March Madness!!!
Round id: 1 
matchup id:
matchup id:
Round id: 2 
matchup id:
```

So, a little bit of it is working. I've done some work in the console and at the matchup level, the matchup object is actually the values "1" and "2", not matchups[0] and matchups[1], as expected, which is why there is no "id" attribute next to the matchup levels. I'm not sure how much "magic" there is in Ember data by using conventions, and can't find any examples that use this level of hierarchy. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I'm including my models so as they are now, with the first responder's recommendations. I'm seeing the same results.

```
App.Tournament = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    active_round_index: DS.attr('number'),
    rounds: DS.hasMany('App.Round', { embedded: 'always' })
});

App.Round = DS.Model.extend({
    tournament: DS.belongsTo('App.Tournament'),
    matchups: DS.hasMany('App.Matchup', { embedded: 'always' })
});

App.Matchup = DS.Model.extend({
    round: DS.belongsTo('App.Round'),
    seats: DS.hasMany('App.Seat', { embedded: 'always' })
});

App.Seat = DS.Model.extend({
    matchup: DS.belongsTo('App.Matchup'),
    entries: DS.hasMany('App.Entry', { embedded: 'always' })
});

App.Entry = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    seats: DS.hasMany('App.Seat')
});
```

** ANOTHER UPDATE **

So, as it turns out, the documented usage of the Ember.RSVP.Promise won't use all of the "magic" of Ember Data, which needs the RESTAdapter to do the fanciness. I plugged in the RESTAdapter and now things are working much better.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what your models look like, but one problem could be that you don't have the hasMany relationship definitions on your model marked as {embedded: 'always'}.  This tells the ember serializer how to handle your related models when serializing and extracting.

example:

```
App.Round = DS.Model.extend({
    tournament: DS.belongsTo('tournament'),
    matchups: DS.hasMany('matchup', { embedded: 'always' })
});
```

Comment: I've updated the original post with my models, I added your recommendation but it didn't help just yet.